# What does $||\textbf u|+|\textbf v||$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$ be two vectors of $\mathbb R^n$, what does $$||\textbf u|+|\textbf v||$$ mean?

Since $|\textbf u|$ and $|\textbf v|$ are the length of $\textbf u$ and $\textbf v$, this means they are some constants. Then what does the length of the sum of two constant mean?

This is the original question:  Show that for $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$ two vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, $|\textbf u+\textbf v| \geq ||\textbf u|-|\textbf v||$
.

Comment: Have you heard of the Cauchy-Schwartz Theorem?

Comment: I believe there's a typo, it should be $| |u| - |v||$

Comment: It should mean the absolute value of $|\mathbf u| +|\mathbf v|$, but that just seems redundant, and the inequality is very wrong. Do you mean minus instead of plus, as in the reverse triangle inequality?

Comment: Are you certain it is $||u|+|v||$ and not $||u||+||v||$?

Comment: Correct form should be this:
$$
\|u + v\| \geq |\,\|u\| - \|v\|\,|
$$
that is, norm of a sum is not smaller than the absolute value of the difference of norms.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, it should be a minus instead of a plus in the inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not unusual to overload the symbol for absolute value, as to mean both the norm of an $n$-dimensional vector, as well as the absolute value of a scalar (which is the one-dimensional norm). The inequality you are asked to prove is therefore this:

> the norm of the vector $\bf{u}+\bf{v}$ is at least the absolute value of the difference of the norms of the vectors $\bf{u},\bf{v}$.

Answer (score 0):

$||u||$ can be interpreted to signify the distance of the vector $u$ from the origin.

$| ~||u|| - ||v|| ~| $ can be interpreted to signify the (**positive**) *magnitude* of the difference between how close $u$ is to the origin vs how close $v$ is from the origin.

$||u + v||$ can be interpreted to signify the distance of the vector $(u+v)$ from the origin.

What the assertion is therefore saying is that

the distance of the vector $(u + v)$ from the origin will not be less than the magnitude of the difference between the distance of $u$ from the origin vs the distance of $v$ from the origin.

**Addendum**

The following *two dimensional* visualization stretches intuition so that the assertion *makes sense*.

Imagine WLOG, that $||u|| > ||v||.$  Consider two concentric circles, both centered at the origin, with one circle of radius $||u||$, and one circle of radius $||v||$.

Then, $u$ will be **somewhere** on the outer circle, and $v$ will be **somewhere** on the inner circle.

Consider the line segment $L$ between $u$ and the origin.

Construe $||u + v||$ as $||u - (-v)||$ which signifies the (positive) distance between the vectors $u$ and $(-v)$.

The **only** time that $||u - (-v)||$ will be equal to $||u|| - ||v||$ is when
the vector $(-v)$ happens to be on the line segment $L$.

If the vector $(-v)$ stays on the inner concentric circle, but moves away from the point where the line segment $L$ intersects the inner circle, then $||u - (-v)||$ **increases**.